# Ubuntu 14 installing phpmyadmin newbie question

Tags: apache2, password, mysql, phpmyadmin

Okay did a search first, and a whole bunch of folks are having problems with this one however my problem seems to be reasonably unique ... i.e. am doing something obviously wrong.

Am getting the following error on install right after entering the password for mysql

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using      │
 │ password: YES)

Have no idea what the root password is, am using the one that allows me su access???

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation process will not ask you for the root password nor for your personal user password but for the password of the **database user** root. This is, if you dont changed it, initaly empty.

You should run

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

and set a mysql root password when asked for it. Then restart installation of phpmyadmin with the now well known mysql root password.